# Create SQLite database using PhoneGap in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to create SQLite database using Android PhoneGap, but the database is created with the file name "app_database:test.db".

It is not creating inside app_database folder and when I am trying to pull it is not coming out.

Code below:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: What version of Phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this not the code to create sqlite database, its code for local storage like websql.
go through the link below and read the title of the phonegap storage doc carefully.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Can you give a summary of the link?